# Can variables be used in function call in ellipsis functions in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, ellipsis

For this function that takes variable number of arguments,

```
void func(int count, ...)  // ellipsis function
{
// function definition
}
```

Can a function call be made like follows :

```
int a{};
double b{};
string c{};

func(3,a,b,c); // using actual variables instead of fixed values in function call
```

My question is when an ellipsis function is called does it always has to be just `fixed` values like `func(3,5,2.7,"Hi")` or can variables be supplied in the function call like so `func(3,a,b,c)`?

Comment: An ellipse is an elongated circle.  I think the term you need is ellipsis.

Comment: And C++ is fine with using variables for ellipsis functions.  But the function needs to have a way of determining the type of the parameters.

Comment: For further research, try "variadic function arguments"

Comment: Would it help if you used a different function for your example? Instead of `func()`, maybe ask about [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)? That takes a variable number of arguments, and it is even the example of such a function given by [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic).

Comment: @JaMiT That's very similar to the kind of use I'm trying to achieve. Only `printf()` allows you to display values whereas I'm trying to manipulate values in the function. Can you explain how `printf()` acheives this?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma printf uses va_args an older C mechanism. In C++ you have the option to use Variadic Templates which allow you to also access type information of the arguments you put in (instead of having to assume or specify in a string like printf).

Comment: @PeterT Can you suggest any reference so I can do some research on it?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma I wouldn't be able to explain it better than cppreference does. (Follow the second link in my earlier comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that passing classes like `std::string`, with non-trivial copy constructor or nontrivial move constructor or non-trivial destructor, may not be supported and has "implementation-defined" semantics. You have to check your compiler documentation on how such classes are passed or check if they are supported at all.

> Can variables be used in function call in ellipsis functions in C++

Yes.

> Can a function call be made like follows

Yes.

> when an ellipsis function is called does it always has to be just fixed values like func(3,5,2.7,"Hi")

No.

> can variables be supplied in the function call like so func(3,a,b,c)?

Yes.

> Can you suggest any reference so I can do some research on it?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#call-12

And in C++ you should strongly prefer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack , because of type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Though ellipsis gives us some useful functionality, it is quite dangerous to use them. When using ellipsis, the compiler does not check the type of arguments passed to the function. So the compiler does not throw any error if arguments are of different types. Even if pass string, double, or bool type values are passed to the average() function it returns return an unexpected value, the compiler does not throw any error.

Source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ellipsis-in-c-with-examples/

Comment: This does not help!